# how to SET store procedure output value to a declare variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My Store procedure will return a ID after insert Date , i am successful insert to data , but every time my `@test` value will be 0 , but actually my Store procedure is returning a ID of 123 for example .

My code as below

```
declare @INS_ID int, @test int

EXEC @test = Ins_Data 4,'Apple','Apple','Apple',@INS_ID OUTPUT
select @test
```

Comment: Why doesn't `@INS_ID`contain the id? That's an output parameter and the new record id can bew assigned to that within the procedure. Then there is no need for the @test variable at all.

Comment: I am calling the store procedure within another store procedure . thanks

Comment: That doesn't matter. Did you write the `Ins_Data` procedure? Is there a `Return` statement in it? I doubt there is, if your `@test`variable always contains 0. Does the `@INS_ID`variable contain the new id after you execute the procedure?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are confusing stored procedure return values with output parameters - consider this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestProc @i INT OUTPUT
AS
    SET @i = 2;
    RETURN 1;
```

If you then call

```
DECLARE @a INT, @b INT;
EXECUTE @a = dbo.TestProc @b OUT;
SELECT  @a, @b;
```

@a will be 1 (because of `RETURN 1` in the procedure), @b will be 2 because it is set as 2 within the procedure.

**[Demo on SQL Fidlle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aefb6/2)**